# c# DataGrid BindingListCollectionView custom filter throwing invalid usage of aggregate function mean

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, collectionviewsource, bindinglist

I have a collection view in which I would like to apply the filter greater than average.
Issue is column type is string.
So normal greater than with any number works perfect after converting to double type, issue is how to do it for average.
I tried following code:

```
collectionView.CustomFilter = $"CONVERT({col}, 'System.Double') > AVG([{col}])";
```

as expected, it breaks as AVG can't be applied on string type. But when i tried to put

```
AVG([CONVERT({col}, 'System.Double')])
```

it doesn't evaluate conversion.

Any suggestion to overcome it?

Comment: If that filter syntax is SQL then you have reversed the parameters. I guess you have to use SQL datatypes too then. Try this: $"CONVERT(float, {col}) > AVG([{col}])".

Comment: The convert function works only in Sql Server, so you may want to use the ANSI equivalent instead: CAST({col} AS float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a limitation of the underlying `DataView.RowFilter` (and `DataColumn.Expression`) supported [Aggregates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8#aggregates):

> An aggregate can only be applied to a single column and no other expressions can be used inside the aggregate.

The only way to overcome it I see is to add (dynamically) calculated column to the underlying `DataTable` which performs the `CONVERT`, and then use that column inside the filter expression.

Something like this:

```
var dataView = collectionView.SourceCollection as DataView;
if (dataView.Table.Columns[col].DataType == typeof(string))
{
    var calcCol = col + "_Double";
    if (!dataView.Table.Columns.Contains(calcCol))
        dataView.Table.Columns.Add(calcCol, typeof(double), $"CONVERT({col}, 'System.Double')");
    col = calcCol;
}
collectionView.CustomFilter = $"{col} > AVG({col})";
```